# Converting kivy code to android app with firebase

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am trying to convert kivy and kivymd code to app using ubuntu latest version. then i get error.
when i try to install proto it says no module named proto
While converting kivy code to apk whick contain modules as

```
import os
import re
from datetime import date
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage
from firebase_admin import firestore
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp, mm
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem, OneLineAvatarIconListItem, IRightBodyTouch, \
    TwoLineAvatarIconListItem, ThreeLineAvatarListItem, OneLineAvatarListItem, ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDTimePicker, MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
```

I used buildozer file as-

```
    05-16 13:57:20.830 12489[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = PBM Student Connect

# (str) Package name
package.name = pbm

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.pbm

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,jpeg

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,requests,firebase-admin,cachetools,urllib3,charset_normalizer,idna,pyasn1,pyasn1_modules,rsa


# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = appicon.jpeg

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class instead of PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk).
# android.release_artifact = aab

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

and the error i got is as

```
 12526 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
    05-16 13:57:20.830 12489 12526 I python  : AND: Ran string
    05-16 13:57:20.830 12489 12526 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
    05-16 13:57:20.824 12489 12489 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:187892): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.pbm.pbm/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/math.cpython-38.so" dev="mmcblk0p87" ino=150206 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
    05-16 13:57:20.835 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.824 12489 12489 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:187893): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.pbm.pbm/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_datetime.cpython-38.so" dev="mmcblk0p87" ino=212851 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
    05-16 13:57:20.850 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.834 12489 12489 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:187894): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.pbm.pbm/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_heapq.cpython-38.so" dev="mmcblk0p87" ino=208101 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
    05-16 13:57:20.844 12489 12489 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:187895): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.pbm.pbm/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_json.cpython-38.so" dev="mmcblk0p87" ino=208136 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
    05-16 13:57:20.869 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.883 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.888 13504 13504 D NavBarTintController: onSampleCollected 0.0
    05-16 13:57:20.900 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.950 12854 12854 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) com.mi.android.globalminusscreen identical 3 lines
    05-16 13:57:20.967 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.979   507   507 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0::IServicetracker/default in either framework or device manifest.
    05-16 13:57:20.986 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:20.999 13504 13504 D NavBarTintController: onSampleCollected 0.0
    05-16 13:57:21.001 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:21.010   507   507 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0::IServicetracker/default in either framework or device manifest.
    05-16 13:57:21.017 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:21.301 12854 12854 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) com.mi.android.globalminusscreen identical 17 lines
    05-16 13:57:21.317 12854 12854 I AssistHolderContentView: forceFitSystemWindows pb = 0
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  :   File "/home/cc/p/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  :   File "/home/cc/p/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pbm/arm64-v8a/google/cloud/firestore/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  :   File "/home/cc/p/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pbm/arm64-v8a/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  :   File "/home/cc/p/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pbm/arm64-v8a/google/cloud/firestore_v1/types/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  :   File "/home/cc/p/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pbm/arm64-v8a/google/cloud/firestore_v1/types/common.py", line 16, in <module>
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proto'
    05-16 13:57:21.319 12489 12526 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to install https://pypi.org/project/0proto/and then add it to the requirements list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add protobuf_cpp to your requirements in buildozer file. Remove your ".buildozer" folder from both project and home, rebuild project.

If doesnt work, find "proto" in your virtualenv (most probably under site-packages/google) and if it is pure Python copy and paste into root path of your project.